# Click event on highcharts chrosshair

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have some Highcharts charts but the click event can only be triggered on a series point.

Is there any way to click on the entire crosshair to get the column category (`this.category` on series click event) ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to attach events to a crosshair. If you use a crosshair with categories, then you can use [chart.events.click](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click). In the callback you can search for the closest point and its category.

```
chart: {
      events: {
        click: function (e) {
          alert(this.series[0].searchPoint(e, true).category);
        }
      }
    },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/jc8vmh4z/1/

The advantage of attaching click to the whole plot area is that if you do the same with a crosshair, then you will need to take into consideration its 'z-index', because it might be get covered by grid lines, points, etc.